# IFNUM condition is not working for affiliation counter

Tags: conditionals

I am using `authblk.sty` and using the `\ifnum\value{}>1` concept using to switch the affiliation. But I can't able to get the `if then else` condition output.

My requirement is

#### Condition 1

If the affiliation is count is one the affiliation number should be relax.

#### Condition 2

If the affiliation is count is more than one the affiliation number should be counter 1,2,3 etc.

I mentioned my `\ifnum` condition in my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\usepackage{letltxmacro,xparse}

\newcounter{affiliations}
\LetLtxMacro{\authblkauthor}{\author}
\LetLtxMacro{\authblkaffil}{\affil}

\ifnum\value{affiliations}>1
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{%
  \authblkauthor[\theauthors]{#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\affil}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{affiliations}%
  \authblkaffil[\theaffiliations]{#1}%
}
\else
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{%
  \authblkauthor[\theauthors]{#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\affil}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{affiliations}%
  \authblkaffil[$\relax$]{#1}%
}
\fi

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}

\author{Junli Liu}
\author{James Rowe}
\author{Keith Lindsey}

\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences,
  The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\affil{Some other laboratory, Elsewhere}
\affil{Another laboratory, Somewhere Else}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But my `\ifnum` condition is not working properly. Always executed `\else` part only. `\ifnum\value{affiliation}>1` part is not executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ifnum` does nothing in the way you are using it.

To achieve what you want you need the `totcount` package and to register your `affiliations` counter with it.

```
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{affiliations}
```

Then the redefinition of `\affil` must be

```
\renewcommand{\affil}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{affiliations}%
  \ifnum\totvalue{affiliations}>1%
    \authblkaffil[\theaffiliations]{#1}%
  \else%
    \authblkaffil[$\relax$]{#1}%
  \fi%
}
```

MWE (needs at least two compilations)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\usepackage{letltxmacro,xparse}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{affiliations}

\LetLtxMacro{\authblkauthor}{\author}
\LetLtxMacro{\authblkaffil}{\affil}

\renewcommand{\author}[1]{%
  \authblkauthor[\theauthors]{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\affil}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{affiliations}%
  \ifnum\totvalue{affiliations}>1%
    \authblkaffil[\theaffiliations]{#1}%
  \else%
    \authblkaffil[$\relax$]{#1}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}

\author{Junli Liu}
\author{James Rowe}
\author{Keith Lindsey}

\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences,
  The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\affil{Some other laboratory, Elsewhere}
\affil{Another laboratory, Somewhere Else}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

This is the result if you have only one `\affil`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\usepackage{letltxmacro,xparse}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{affiliations}

\LetLtxMacro{\authblkauthor}{\author}
\LetLtxMacro{\authblkaffil}{\affil}

\renewcommand{\author}[1]{%
  \authblkauthor[\theauthors]{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\affil}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{affiliations}%
  \ifnum\totvalue{affiliations}>1%
    \authblkaffil[\theaffiliations]{#1}%
  \else%
    \authblkaffil[$\relax$]{#1}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}

\author{Junli Liu}
\author{James Rowe}
\author{Keith Lindsey}

\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences,
  The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You'd also probably want to redefine `\author` in this way:

```
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{%
  \ifnum\totvalue{affiliations}>1%
    \authblkauthor[\theauthors]{#1}%%
  \else%
    \authblkauthor[$\relax$]{#1}%
  \fi%
}
```

so that when there is only one `\author` and one `\affil` you have no numbers in it.

Comment: Your code example the first affiliation number is always empty. I can't get required output. But the requirement is if the second and third affil is commented in the tex file the first affil is empty. Otherwise If more than one affil available in the tex file the stepcounter is counted 1,2,3...etc

Comment: sorry the first example is executed perfectly. I got the solution. Thank you...

Comment: See the last edit for `\author` too. Maybe it improves what you are trying to achieve.